# Memory to memory DMA to move top half-word

Tags: stm32, dma

I set it as a goal to understand mem-to-mem DMA on an STM32, but I think I must be missing something.  Say I have an array of uint32_t and I want the top 16 bits, and I want to get it via DMA because it's off some huge buffer.  First, I set up two arrays of uint8_t (because that's what most data receiving peripherals want), i.e. in main.c, global scope, I have

```
static uint8_t buff_in[64];
static uint8_t buff_out[32];
```

I have the following ISR:

```
void DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if ((DMA1->ISR)&(1<<22))  // Half Transfer Complete
  {
    // Do something small
  }

  if ((DMA1->ISR)&(1<<21))  // Transfer Complete
  {
    // Do something small
  }
}
```

Now in main() I will use pointers to 16 and 32 bit to get the data how I want it:

```
/* Pointers to the buffers with the correct alignments */
uint32_t *in_32  = (uint32_t*)buff_in;
uint16_t *out_16 = (uint16_t*)buff_out;

/* Fill the memory with something easy to see */
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
  in_32[i]  = ((uint32_t)(0xAFAF - i * 3 + i * 37) << 16) | ((uint32_t)0xE5E7);
  out_16[i] = (uint16_t)0; // Zero out while we are here
}

/* Point to buffer + 16 bits */
uint32_t *src  = (uint32_t*)&buff_in[2];
uint16_t *dest = out_16;

/* DMA1 Channel 6 config */
DMA1_Channel6->CCR = 0;     // Reset

DMA1_Channel6->CCR |= DMA_CCR_MEM2MEM;                   // Mem-to-mem mode
DMA1_Channel6->CCR |= DMA_CCR_PSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_1; // Dest size 16-bit, Src size 32-bit
DMA1_Channel6->CCR |= DMA_CCR_DIR;                       // Read from memory (mem is src)
DMA1_Channel6->CCR |= DMA_CCR_PINC | DMA_CCR_MINC;       // Increment pointers
DMA1_Channel6->CCR |= (DMA_CCR_TCIE | DMA_CCR_HTIE | DMA_CCR_TEIE); // Enable interrupts

/* Enable IRQ */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel6_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel6_IRQn);

DMA1_Channel6->CMAR  = (uint32_t)src;
DMA1_Channel6->CPAR  = (uint32_t)dest;
DMA1_Channel6->CNDTR = 16;

/* Enable DMA */
DMA1_Channel6->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN;

/* Main loop */
while (1)
{
}
```

If `src` just points to `buff_in`, then I get the bottom 16 bits fine and I see a bunch of `0xE7` `0xE5`.  But when I point to `buff_in + 2` as above, **I get the same thing!?!**  This confuses me very much.  I thought I was passing the address + offset so that I would get the next half-words.

This is an L476.

I also modified the code to just use registers. Same result except I get the ISR, which I didn't before.

Comment: I’ve not used the dma in the stm32, but could it be an alignment issue?

Comment: Which STM32? Please add in the exact model you are using. Different models have different DMA controllers so we would not even know which reference manual to read for you.

Comment: You seem to be using a mix-n-match of parts of the STM HAL library (`HAL_DMA_RegisterCallback(...)`) along with direct register access (`DMA1_Channel6->CPAR = (uint32_t)src;`. You really need to pick one method of accessing & configuring the DMA peripheral and stick with it. You also seem to be missing a lot of the required configuration of the DMA peripheral - is there more you're not showing us?

Comment: @Justme I meant to include that, edited the OP.  Maybe you could also point out specifically what trigger words you will be seeking in the RM.  I've already read through it quite a bit, but evidently I'm not seeing what you think you will see.

Comment: @brhans Thanks, I edited the question to just use the registers.  It's certainly more clear, but I still get the same result, albeit with the ISR working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is described on page 336 of the ref manual:

> Transfer size of source and destination are independent (byte, half-word, word),
> emulating packing and unpacking. **Source and destination addresses must be
> aligned on the data size.**

Also, on page 356 in the register descriptions:

> When PSIZE = 10 (32 bits), bits 1 and 0 of PA[31:0] are ignored. Access is automatically aligned to a word address.

So `src = buff_in;` has the same effect as `src = buff_in + 2;`, because the `+2` is ignored when PSIZE is configured as 32-bits.
The same condition is described for MSIZE on the next page.

It looks like the only way to achieve what you're trying to do would be to force your src buffer to be misaligned when you load it so that it's aligned as you want it to to be when the DMA reads it.

For example you could declare
`uint8_t buff_in[66];`
and then
`uint32_t *in_32  = (uint32_t*)(buff_in + 2);`
so now when you run the for loop to pre-load it with 32-bit values they'll be 'misaligned' by 2 bytes, but 'correctly aligned' for how you want the DMA to read them.

I'm not sure how your L476 handles misaligned accesses by the core (as opposed to the DMA above) - it's possible that this might generate a UsageFault, depending on the instructions your C compiler generates for the `in_32[i]  = ...` line in your `for(...)` loop.
If this does happen then you'll have to do something like load a temporary `uint32_t` variable with the value you want to write, then use a `memcpy` to actually write it to the buffer, for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Oh dear lord sorry - I must have read that thing on p.356 fifty times and it never sunk in.  Interesting idea to misalign first, and it works (at least without compile optimizations).  It gives me 16 bits of garbage first, but it fills as originally expected if I instead point to `buff_in - 2` (obviously a terrible idea that I would never do).  I learned something today, thanks!